# Difference between iteration and recursion in binary search tree insertion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement insertion in a binary search tree. According to my logic, both the recursion and iteration are performing very similar tasks - however, my recursive function works but my iterative solution doesn't. What is the difference in execution? Why is the iteration function not working? (Ignore the different return types)

The error that occurs is that in the case of iteration, only one element gets inserted properly. Successive insertions do not work.

Class Definition :

```
class Node
{
    public:
        Node(int x, Node *l = NULL, Node *r = NULL)
        {
            val = x;
            left = l;
            right = r;
        }
        int val;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
};
```

Iteration :

```
Node* insert(Node* &root, int x)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node(x);
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = newNode;
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* travNode = root;
        while (travNode != NULL)
        {
            if (x < travNode->val)
                travNode = travNode->left;
            else
                travNode = travNode->right;
        }
        travNode = newNode;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Recursion :

```
void insert(Node* &root, int x)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(x);
        root = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x < root->val)
            insert(root->left, x);
        else
            insert(root->right, x);
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: You are not modifying the tree in the iterative version. You are modifying a local variable `travNode` that gets thrown away in the end.

Answer (score 1):

In your recursion, your whole function executes when you call insert() which is correct.

In the iterative solution, you find a node which would be the parent node for your new node, but you overwrite that node with the new node instead of setting it as a child.

You need to have `travNode->left = newNode` or `travNode->right = newNode` somewhere.

Comment: I understand what I have to do to make the iterative method work, but could you tell me why the existing code doesn't work? In both this case and the recursive case, I am reaching the place where I need to insert, then inserting a new Node.